# Facebook whitehat settings

Tags: settings, privacy, facebook, menu

I am trying to enable Facebook whitehat to test the Facebook Android app. I
went here:

https://facebook.com/whitehat/researcher-settings

I click "Enable the Whitehat Settings menu for your Facebook account". Then I
click "Facebook Lite for Android". Then I go here:

https://facebook.com/whitehat/researcher-settings/help

Under "Enable setting from Facebook on Android", it says go to the "Bookmark
menu". I don't know what that is, so I just click on the menu button on the top
right corner. Then I click Settings, then Privacy. On the next screen, I don't
see anything for Whitehat.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the "Whitehat settings" option does not show up immediately, but after about one day upon enabling the option.